# Construction of Wiener Process using integral of covariance multiplied by a function

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I read in the notes of Stochastic Processes that there is a construction of Wiener Process (knowing that $Cov(W_s, W_t)=min(s,t)$ ) which going like this:

consider operator $Q$ on $C([0,1])$
$$Qf(t)= \int_0^1 min(s,t) f(s) ds $$
find the functions $f_k$ such, that
$$Qf_k= \lambda_k f_k$$
then the Wiener Process has a form:
$$W(t)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k X_k f_k$$

in the notes, there are also explicit forms of $f_k$ and $a_k$. 
My question is why this algorithm works? Does someone know the proof?

reference - part of italian notes to Stochastic Processes course:
http://en.file-upload.net/download-11221924/psZ.pdf.html

Comment: What is your reference

Comment: @Zbigniew It's part of italian notes to Stochastic Processes course. I can also upload full notes.
http://en.file-upload.net/download-11221924/psZ.pdf.html

Comment: What is $X_k$? ${}{}$

Comment: @Ian Probably i.i.d. standard normal random variables.